# What is the difference between a normal C:\ drive & an -IC:\ Drive in A windows Machine

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, cmd.exe, path, pathfinder

Recently, Just now tried to install [PyGTK](https://pypi.org/project/PyGTK/) for building python User Interface Modules.
Just to mess around With, But It's Saying Can't install PyGTK Without PyObject,
So I Also tried to install this via pip install inside a command line tool,
But I Noticed a funny Path directory that I've never come across before & was wondering What it is,
What it is used for Or How it is Different(Appart from the Name) From The Normal Generic C:\ drive.. Included a picture below.
But the Path is `-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um` When Trying to search for this drive in windows explorer a dialogue pops up saying I'd need an external program to view this drive? Has anyone seen this before or Know what it is, is it system reserved, back-up etc or something else?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screen-pics like this. They are quite unreadable for most of us in these colors/resolution and totally useless for visually impaired people that need to use a screen-reader. Copy/Paste the text itself and put it in a code or quote block please

Comment: @tonny Yeah, I didn't realize quite how bad quality, The screen shot was until after I uploaded it, but have included the path within the question so will leave it up here for now.

Comment: Without the context of the screenshot (the full command-line) ) your question text itself is pretty incomprehensible. The lack of line-breaks doesn't help either... You can insert a line break in the text by ending a line in the markdown-editor with 2 extra spaces.

Comment: @Tonny I've replaced the screen shot with one that has a bigger font size, so It might be a bit easier to read & included the whole command

Answer (score 2):

The -I is a command-line option to the pygobject command (it usually denotes a folder in which to find "include" files) which takes a parameter (a path) immediately following the -I.
In other words: the -I is NOT part of the path itself.